# sed command gives error :sed: -e expression #1, char 50: unterminated `s' command

Tags: perl, sed

I used `grep` to find out whether a particular line exists in a file or not like this:

```
my $grepval=`grep "$conn[$i]" filename`;
```

which is correct but after this I now want to delete the `grepval` from the file using sed like this:

```
sed -i "s/$grepval//g" filename`;
```

which gives me error `sed: -e expression #1, char 50: unterminated`s' command`.
Please help on how to resolve it.thanks

there's probably a / in $grepval also it can be multilines – RC. 39 mins ago

SA291 ERROR CODE---->>> -3 ERROR_NO_RESULT_FOUND .this is my $grepval.I used a different delimiter also like this :sed -i "s|$grepval||g" /home/abc/Desktop/xyz.txt.but its still giving me the same error.

Comment: there's probably a `/` in `$grepval` also it can be multilines

Comment: SA291 ERROR CODE---->>> -3 ERROR_NO_RESULT_FOUND .this is my $grepval.I used a different delimiter also like this :`sed -i "s|$grepval||g" /home/abc/Desktop/xyz.txt`.but its still giving me the same error

Comment: Question is, why do you first grep to get a line, then perform a substitution to get rid of that line? And then shell out to `sed` inside Perl? Sheesh. Open the file in perl, print lines to a copy of the file, but don't print lines that match your grep value. Done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

U'll have to use sed -i instead of sed -e to make the changes in the file .. -e is used for expressions whereas -i is required when u need to modify the files and save 'em after the modifications.. also chomp would also work to resolve this issue.. The grepval var might ave a newline character at the end.

Sammy

Answer (score 2):

Put this in your code just before the `sed` invocation:

```
print "[$grepval]\n";
```

and I guarantee there'll be a `/` in there somewhere, probably around character number 48.

One way to solve it is to preprocess `$grepval` so that you turn it into a properly formatted search string for `sed` or, if possible, choose a delimiter that you know *won't* appear in the string (`sed` allows different delimiters):

```
sed -i "s?$grepval??g" filename
```

Comment: No ther is no / in the grepval output.still there is is this error

Answer (score 1):

If the replacement/pattern contain `/`, then you can't use `/` as the delimiter.

Use a different delimiter:

```
sed -i "s|$grepval||g" filename
```

Comment: there is no / in the replacement pattern still there is this error.is there any other alternative besides sed

Comment: if ($html =~ m#^(\d+)\/(\d+)$#)
{my $grepval=`grep "$conn[$i]" /home/abc/Desktop/xyz.txt`;          if ( $grepval ne "")
 { `sed -e "s?$grepval??g" /home/abc/Desktop/xyz.txt`;}                                                            if i print $grepval it gives this output :SA291 ERROR CODE---->>> -3 ERROR_NO_RESULT_FOUND ,which is OK but I now want to remove this line from xyz.txt which is not happening bcoz sed is giving error

Answer (score 0):

you could get a list of file names that contain the string in question

```
my @files = qx#grep -l $search_string $filenameExpression#;

foreach my $f ( @files )
{
  chomp($f);
    # make sure your input doesn't have slash "/" then use hash "#"
  my $ret = `perl -pi -e's#$search_string##g' $f`;  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a newline in `$grepval` (or another "hidden" character). Get rid of it with `chomp`.

Also you might consider using the list form of `system()` to avoid problems with shell metacharacters (just putting arguments into `""` does not help always) and try to escape possible regexp metacharacters with `quotemeta()` to get the script more robust. Even better to do the whole thing completely in Perl. For example, `sed -i` is not portable and works probably only on Linux systems.

Comment: i used chomp ,now its not giving any error but not deleting the value of $grepval from the text file.I used `sed -e 's/$grepval//g' /home/abc/Desktop/xyz.txt`;  please help

Answer (score 0):

This is very old, but comes up in a search, and has no proper answer to date.

If you are doing a substitution using sed, you need to protect against shell expansion where not wanted, and force it where desired. The error here implies that the actual sed search was done against 'grepval' not the actual error found that 'grepval' contains.

Try:   `sed -i 's|'"${grepval}"'||g' xyz.txt`

That is a ' followed by a " and the ${ and reverse order after the }

Added because the font makes it very hard to read!

Example (using pipe symbol as delimiter):
`# grepval="THIS"; echo $grepval; echo "${grepval}"; echo '"${grepval}"'`

`#THIS`

`#THIS`

`#"${grepval}"`   # the ' chars restrict expansion by the shell

`# echo "THIS is a mess" > test.txt`

`# sed -i 's|'"${grepval}"'|THAT|g' test.txt ; cat test.txt`

`#THAT is a mess`   # and sed then substitutes inside the s// command.

sed needs to have BOTH the ' and the ". Sometimes the shell needs to be 'told' how to handle the expansion. One common spot is in test clauses. You can play with

`if [ $grepval = "THAT" ] ; then echo "yes" ;  else  echo "no"; fi`

`if [ ${grepval} = "THAT" ] ; then echo "yes" ;  else  echo "no"; fi`

`if [ "$grepval" = "THAT" ] ; then echo "yes" ;  else  echo "no"; fi`

`if [ "${grepval}" = "THAT" ] ; then echo "yes" ;  else  echo "no"; fi`

to get an idea of what happens. (And the whole "${grepval}" *always* works.